# Form added dynamically by AJAX is not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a table and every line in this table is a form, table is refreshed asynchronously in the first code part (reset function) using AJAX , I need to synchronously submit the form coming as a result of the html function in the success part, the submitting code (on click) will call an fpdf instance and show the result within an iframe. submitting would function correctly until I refresh or add a new line, form would not synchronously submit then.

the reset function:

```
function reset() {

$.ajax({
url : 'php_file.php',
type : 'post',
data : {reset: 1},

success : function(response) {

    $( "#datagrid" ).remove();
    $('#datagrid_div').html(response);

    }
 });
}
```

the submission function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit_Btn", function(){

      var index = $(this).prop("value");

      var values = {};

      values['key_'+index] = $('#key_' + index).val();

      $.post('php_file.php', values,function(result){

      $("#PDF_Div").show();
 });

 return 0;
});
```

I have tried too many answers mentioned here on this website but none of it was helping in this problem.

the html part looks as follows:

```
<input type='button' onclick='reset();'/>
<div id='datagrid_div'>

  <table id='datagrid'>
  <tr>
  <form target="pdf_frame" method="POST" action="php_file.php">
<td>info_1</td>
  <input type='hidden' id='key_1'/>
  <input type='submit' class='submit_Btn' value='1'/>
  </form>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check whether the click event is triggered or not ?

Comment: clicks are being detected, the problem is not about the click event, it is that when I refresh the forms (table lines here) , submit would not fire synchronously , which means that I am only having an empty frame as a result of the click.

Comment: show the response pls.

Comment: before resetting the response is a pdf file generated by fpdf , after resetting , instead of the pdf file , nothing would show inside the frame.

Comment: it seems like your reset function returns something not quite right, maybe the index is not increased ? And sorry for the basic question, but did you use developer tools (browser build in or firebug) to look for errors?

Comment: the result from reset function returns the table again , as you can see it removes the first table using the remove function and after that it calls the table again using the html function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it could work...

1. I cannot see where reset() gets called
2. If reset() does get called, $( "#datagrid" ).remove(); removes the form from being submitted again
3. The table syntax is wrong. You have a tr tag, but no td tag, so the form tag probably gets shoved AFTER the table tag.
4. The form tag references action="php_file.php" which means clicking the submit button will (if the form gets read/rendered correctly) posts data to php_file.php, and does not use your jquery ajax call which means the ajax success call does not execute either.

Suggested changes: put the form tag outside the table. Since you expect ajax to perform form submission, avoid reference it within the form tag.

```
<div id='datagrid_div'>
  <form>
  <table id='datagrid'>
  <tr><td>    
  <input type='hidden' id='key_1'/>
  <input type='submit' class='submit_Btn'/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am not clear why you would want to have a submit button referenced as a class - if the submit button appears more than once, then all will be selected and thus several calls will be posted.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".submit_Btn", function(){

      var index = $(this).prop("value");

      var values = {};

      values['key_'+index] = $('#key_' + index).val();

      $.post('php_file.php', values,function(result){

      $("#PDF_Div").show();
 });

 return 0;
});
</script>
```

I am unsure on how you could direct the PDF to open within an iframe. I would work first on displaying a single text value in your iframe before figuring out how to get the PDF to appear there.

Comment: since it is a datagrid table there is huge amount of rows which means that any click on the print buttons should open the same function , and to detect which button was clicked there is the line `var index = $(this).prop("value");` , as for the text, I tried and since there is no submission there was nothing posted , the whole post function stops working after resetting.

Comment: You've not mentioned if you fixed the tables.  I don't believe you can perform a post submit with target to another frame via ajax - the solution would be to have your iframe to execute the js and then for it to display the pdf (as opposed to the parent window executing the code and targeting the pdf elsewhere).